# Pythonic version of Excel's SUMIF

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to create an extra column based on a number of dimensions per row. So, let's say I have a data frame containing two dimensions (month, country) and a metric (sum). Based on the month dimension, I want the value in the new column to contain the value of that month with a date offset of two months (whilst holding the other dimension the same) – see table below.

In Excel, one could go about as follows:

```
SUMIFS($C:$C,$B:$B,B2,$A:$A,DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)-2,DAY(A2)))
```

In normal language: Sum if (1) the country column contains the same value as the cell I'm referencing to in the country column in the current row and (2) the month column contains the same value as the cell I'm referencing in the month column in the current row but with a date offset of minus 2 months.

```
+--------+---------+-----+------+
|  month | country | sum | sum2 |
+--------+---------+-----+------+
| 1/1/19 | DE      |  58 |    0 |
| 2/1/19 | DE      |  61 |    0 |
| 3/1/19 | DE      |  89 |   58 |
| 4/1/19 | DE      |  45 |   61 |
| 5/1/19 | DE      |  33 |   89 |
| 6/1/19 | DE      |  17 |   45 |
| 1/1/19 | NL      |  18 |    0 |
| 2/1/19 | NL      |  23 |    0 |
| 3/1/19 | NL      |  56 |   18 |
| 4/1/19 | NL      |  22 |   23 |
| 5/1/19 | NL      |  49 |   56 |
| 6/1/19 | NL      |  64 |   22 |
+--------+---------+-----+------+
```

Comment: You might consider that Pandas is good at manipulating multiple dimensions of data and can group data. It is included in Anaconda and other frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm reasonably sure this should do it:

```
(df.merge(df.assign(month=df.month + pd.DateOffset(months=2)),
          on=['month', 'country'],
          how='left',
          suffixes=['', '2'])
    .groupby(['country', 'month'], as_index=False)
    .agg({'sum': 'first',
          'sum2': 'sum'}))

      country      month  sum  sum2
0    DE       2019-01-01   58   0.0
1    DE       2019-02-01   61   0.0
2    DE       2019-03-01   89  58.0
3    DE       2019-04-01   45  61.0
4    DE       2019-05-01   33  89.0
5    DE       2019-06-01   17  45.0
6    NL       2019-01-01   18   0.0
7    NL       2019-02-01   23   0.0
8    NL       2019-03-01   56  18.0
9    NL       2019-04-01   22  23.0
10   NL       2019-05-01   49  56.0
11   NL       2019-06-01   64  22.0
```

Comment: I've applied the ".shift" function, however that only works if your df has the exact amount of rows per dimension (e.g. country). It can pose problems when you're missing rows for certain dimensions.

Comment: @user8674713 Please see the edit. Your data doesn't have such cases but I'm guessing this should cover such situation.

Comment: Fantastic! Just as I was about to reply saying I have a possible solution with merging the df on itself using the DateOffset function I saw your reply. Thanks!